# Solution to search browser-URL-history first before the rest of the WWW

Tags: web-browser, search, google-search

**Yesterday** I spent a [whole day researching](https://superuser.com/questions/1257186/restore-winre-parition-from-wim-image-of-original-so-i-can-make-recovery-medi) a problem I made when setting up a new laptop for Dual Boot with Linux--I deleted a required partition before I created recovery media for a system pre-installed with Windows. I think I've mostly solved the problem. I have recovery media (without system backup). Ok.

**Today** I'm writing some notes about how I did it (and hoping to answer my own question at SuperUser), but I can't find the link with *that one command that I used which did that thing*.

I want to do a web search through page content of just the web pages from yesterday's web history.

How can I do that? Is there a plugin or service or something else which can perform this. I'm sure I'll find the answer before too long, but I would like to have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a promising extension for Firefox: [Show HN: WorldBrain – full text, local search of your browsing history (worldbrain.io)](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17743352)